# Selenium webdriver: how to get all attribute values button search by some value (python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get `code` & `level` attribute values in one button where `key="a488"`

this is html code which has many buttons

```
<button type="button" key="a435" code="11-E22." level="1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addChild(this)"> Add</button>
<button type="button" key="a436" code="11-E22.1" level="2" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addChild(this)"> Add</button>
<button type="button" key="a488" code="11-E22.1.1" level="3" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addChild(this)"> Add</button>
<button type="button" key="a764" code="11-E22.1.2" level="3" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addChild(this)"> Add</button>
```

this my python code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://somewebsite.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-sm']")))
```

and I stuck to search button attribute values where attribute key="a488"

```
driver.find_element(By.????, '????').get_attribute('???')
```

Comment: you would be using the `get_attribute('code')` and `get_attribute('level')` once you have found the element. As for finding the specific button you can search by attribute with xpaths https://www.tutorialspoint.com/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-element-by-attributes-in-python-selenium#:~:text=We%20can%20find%20an%20element,attribute%3D'value'%5D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve element's attribute you need to wait for that element visibility (in case this is a visible element). Based on HTML you shared you can locate that element by `key="a488"` and then get it attributes as following:

```py
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[key="a488"]')))
code_value = element.get_attribute("code")
level_value = element.get_attribute("level")
```

This element can also be located with XPath as well
**UPD**
There are several ways to format a sting with parameters in Python.
For example you can use this:

```py
locator = 'button[key="{}"]'
locator = locator.format('a488')
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator)))
code_value = element.get_attribute("code")
level_value = element.get_attribute("level")
```

Comment: how do i put key variable value in string? 'button[key="{key}"]'

Comment: Currently I am not near my computer. Will answer your later

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//button[@type='button' and @key='a488']")

code = ele.get_attribute("code")

level = ele.get_attribute("level")
```

Comment: how do i put key variable value in string? ".//button[@type='button' and @key='{key}']"

Comment: Prophet will answer this question.